# AngularJS + Typescript controller cant be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to add typescript to AngularJS and I'm getting the following error

```
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'MyController' is not` registered
```

Has anyone clue on what I am doing wrong?

I have created the following class

```
/// <reference path='references/_all.ts' />
var app = angular.module('shop', []);

class MyController {
    constructor($scope: any) {
        $scope.message = { title: "Hello World!!" };
    };
}

app.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

and html:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body ng-app="shop">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
            {{message.title}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using grunt to compile it:

```
/// <reference path='references/_all.ts' />
var app = angular.module('shop', []);
var MyController = (function () {
    function MyController($scope) {
        $scope.message = { title: "Hello World!!" };
    };

    return MyController;
})();
app.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

Comment: post the html where you're including the js files

Comment: @Karim added  the html code

Comment: @Eriks: Don't see any problem with it https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fxqo2c

Comment: @Eriks i don't see the .js inclusion, can you post that specific part in the html?

Comment: @AdityaParab When i use your code - `import { module, IScope } from 'angular';` cant find module angular.

Comment: @Eriks: For that to work, you need to install `@types/angular` like `npm install --save-dev @types/angular`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have link file with app?

```
<script src="./app.js"></script>
```

Here is my solution:

```js
var app = angular.module('shop', []);

var MyController = (function () {
    function MyController($scope) {
        $scope.message = { title: "Hello World!!" };
    }

    return MyController;
})();

app.controller('MyController', MyController);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS + Typescript controller cant be found</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="shop">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
      {{message.title}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```